# Adding features to ArcGIS featureLayer via HTML form and ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.24 and trying to update a featureLayer via an HTML input form. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  


<head>  
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
  <title>MyMap</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/esri/css/main.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/"></script>
    <style>  
    html,   
    body,   
    #map {  
      width:100%;  
      height:100%;  
      margin:0;  
      padding:0;  
    }  

  </style>  
  <script> 
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "dojo/dom",
    "esri/geometry/SpatialReference",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
    map, 
    FeatureLayer,
    Graphic,
    Search,
    Point,
    dom,
    SpatialReference,
    on
) {
  featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://services8.arcgis.com/R1PAHHLiCM5plgJt/arcgis/rest/services/Somepoint/FeatureServer/0",
    outFields: ["*"],
  });
  //for testing purpose
  var extent = {
    XMin: -5120763.26772284,
    XMax: 2036.05706365815,
    YMin: 6120763.26772284,
    YMax: 19997963.9429363,
  };
  var getLongitude = function() {
    return (Math.random() * extent.XMax) + extent.XMin;
  };
  var getLatitude = function() {
    return (Math.random() * extent.YMax) + extent.YMin;
  };

  on(document.getElementById('edit-save'), 'click', function() {
    //create the feature
    var feature = new Graphic();
    var geometry = new Point({
      x: getLongitude(),
      y: getLatitude(),
      spatialReference: new SpatialReference({wkid: 28354})
    });
    feature.geometry = geometry;
    feature.attributes = {
      "Name": document.getElementById('Name').value,
      "Id": document.getElementById('Id').value
    };

    //add to the featureLayer
    var promise = featureLayer.applyEdits({
      addFeatures: [feature]
    });

    promise.then(function(res){
      console.log('new OBJECTID:', res.addFeatureResults[0].objectId);
    }, function(err){
      console.error(err);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>  


<body class="">  
    <div id="" class="">
         <div class="">
             <div class="">
                 <div class="">
                    <h1 class="">Edit Information</h1>
                 </div>
                 <div class="">
                   <form class="">
                       <div class="">
                           <label class="">ID</label>
                           <div class="">
                               <input  type="text" class="" id="Id">
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="">
                           <label class="">Name</label>
                           <div class="">
                               <input  type="text" class="" id="Name">
                           </div>
                       </div>

                    </form>
                 </div>
                 <div class="">
                   <button type="button" class="" id="edit-save">Save Changes</button>

                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you be more precise about the problem you get ?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm trying to add a new feature rather than edit an existing one. I have found it very hard to find much information about how to go about it.

Comment: i've updated my answer

Comment: I am still having issues pushing data. It looks like someone has however there are no geometries. I have posted the updated full codeblock. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i hope you have replaced the `...` with the lines from "your" code

Comment: Indeed, Yes above is the full page i am attempting to run, I will integrate it into the larger page after this works. Thank you for all your help thus far

Comment: You forgot `MapView,` between `map,` and `FeatureLayer,`

Comment: And you are not using api v3.24 but v4.7

Comment: I really appreciate that, Thanks. I think i had been looking at it too long!

Comment: yep that happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** to *add* a feature, you can take a look at the example from the documentation.

Create a new graphic, you will need a geometry and its attributes. You get the attributes from your form
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-Graphic.html#attributes

That featureLayer expects Points. So create a new one with its coordinates (i've put random longitude and latitude) and the spatialreference of the Feature Layer (28354) https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Point.html#constructors-summary

```
var feature = new Graphic();

var geometry = new Point({
  x: 5120763.26,
  y: 97963.94,
  spatialReference: new SpatialReference({wkid: 28354})
});

feature.geometry = geometry;

feature.attributes = {
  "Name": dom.byId('Name').value,
  "Id": dom.byId('Id').value
};
```

Now you can *add* that feature  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#applyEdits

```
const promise = featureLayer.applyEdits({
  addFeatures: [feature]
});
```

Don't forget to add `"esri/geometry/SpatialReference"` as a **required** module

ps: i suggest you to use `dojo/on`, to handle the event of user's click on the `user-save` button, instead of jQuery:

```
require([
  ...
  "esri/geometry/SpatialReference",
  "dojo/on",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
  ...
  SpatialReference,
  on
) {
  featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
    url: "https://services8.arcgis.com/R1PAHHLiCM5plgJt/arcgis/rest/services/Somepoint/FeatureServer/0",
    outFields: ["*"],
  });
  //for testing purpose
  var extent = {
    XMin: -5120763.26772284,
    XMax: 2036.05706365815,
    YMin: 6120763.26772284,
    YMax: 19997963.9429363,
  };
  var getLongitude = function() {
    return (Math.random() * extent.XMax) + extent.XMin;
  };
  var getLatitude = function() {
    return (Math.random() * extent.YMax) + extent.YMin;
  };

  on(dom.byId('edit-save'), 'click', function() {
    //create the feature
    var feature = new Graphic();
    var geometry = new Point({
      x: getLongitude(),
      y: getLatitude(),
      spatialReference: new SpatialReference({wkid: 28354})
    });
    feature.geometry = geometry;
    feature.attributes = {
      "Name": dom.byId('Name').value,
      "Id": dom.byId('Id').value
    };

    //add to the featureLayer
    var promise = featureLayer.applyEdits({
      addFeatures: [feature]
    });
    var promise = featureLayer.applyEdits({
      addFeatures: [feature]
    });
    promise.then(function(res){
      console.log('new OBJECTID:', res.addFeatureResults[0].objectId);
    }, function(err){
      console.error(err);
    });
  });
});
```